# Converting hashmap into javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a hashmap into a object of javascript and then I am passing a key i.e., property of object and want to retrive the value of it;
Hashmap mcl = {AB=1,BC=2,DE=3} .Now when I am sending the value AB then it giving outputbut when  I am passing BC or DE its not. Can any one suggest on it?

```
function getCount(key)
        {

            var map='<%=mcl%>';

            var nmap=new Object();
            var z=map.substr(1, map.length-2);

            var y=z.split(',');
            for(var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
            {
                var k=y[i];
                var m=k.split("=");
                nmap[m[0]]=m[1];
            }
            alert(nmap[key])
        }
```

Comment: Are there spaces after the commas in the hashmap string?

Answer (score 1):

Your example uses `;` as a delimiter (`{AB=1;BC=2;DE=3}`), but your code uses `,` (`z.split(',')`).

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting on a comma `,` but your example is delimited by a semicolon `;`

Change to:

```
var y=z.split(';');
```

Edit: if your data has a comma, and you split on the comma then your code is fine. Are you forgetting to actually call the function? It won't execute unless you call it.

```
getCount('AB');
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej6G4/)**

Comment: Sorry my mistake that is comma.thats why I ams splitting

Comment: obviously m callin it nywaz thanks it is resolved now